# Grove LCD display not working with arduino rev 2 wifi (Unknown error at address 0x3E)

Tags: lcd, arduino-uno-wifi

I am trying to connect Grove 16x2 LCD (White on Blue) to my Arduino uno rev 2 wifi.
So far, I've tried hd44780 library's ioClass examples, but nothing worked. I've then decided to scan ports and when LCD was connected to rev 2 SDA/SCL pins I've got (Unknown error at address 0x3E). So it recognizes that something is connected, but doesn't recognize the LCD. I've also tried to run I2CexpDiag, which also returned "Unknown error at address 0x3E".
I tried the same LCD with Arduino UNO and mkr1010, both work flawlessly. I've also tried connecting the SDA/SCL pins to A4/A5, but nothing there either.
Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-16x2_LCD_Series/ > Step 1. Download the Grove-LCD RGB Backlight Library from Github.

Comment: Just tried it, tried a couple of examples, but nothing comes up on the screen.

Comment: Uno WiFi has some on-board I2C devices. run the I2CScanner sketch

Comment: Yes, it does recognize something on 0x60

Comment: does the scanner show the address of the LCD?

Comment: Yea, like I've mentioned, I get an error "Unknown error at address 0x3E", which is the address of the LCD. However the LCD works with other boards flawlessly

Comment: You are not alone https://forum.arduino.cc/t/issue-with-i2c-between-arduino-uno-wifi-rev2-and-grove-16x2-lcd/609423/2 Except for the base shield switch, no answer is there. Here https://forum.arduino.cc/t/surenoo-rgb-i2c-lcd-unstable-i2c-communication-solved/666902/67 a VERY long thread on a similar LCD/problem. Maybe worth trying this library https://werner.rothschopf.net/202009_arduino_liquid_crystal_wire_en.htm with the Grove settings.

Comment: Yea, have tried that library, but no luck